# Fetch credentials depending on environment

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I can take credentials like explained in the example taken from here - https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#environment

```
stage('Example') {
        environment { 
            CREDS = credentials('MY_CREDS_DEV') 
        }
        steps {
            sh 'echo hello'
        }
}
```

But what I want to do is to get credentials based on some condition.

For example I have `MY_CREDS_DEV` and `MY_CREDS_QA` defined in Jenkins credentials. And I have a property `ENV=dev` defined in Jenkins 'Prepare an environment for the run' section.

I'd like to access credentials based on my environment, i.e. **ENV** property.

I tried to use `CREDS = credentials('MY_CREDS_' + ${ENV})` and tried to extract strings concatenation to a separate function and call it like `CREDS = credentials(concatenate(${ENV}))` but I got `Internal function call parameters must be strings.`

So seems I can put only a string to `credentials()` function which basically means to hardcode it. But how can I choose which credentials to use - dev or qa?

Comment: Can supply the full example including the `concatenate()` function?

Answer (score 4):

Use `CREDS = credentials('MY_CREDS_' + ENV)` or `CREDS = credentials("MY_CREDS_${ENV}")`. `${ENV}` will not become `'dev'`but `${'dev'}` and therefore is no string.

#### For completeness:

In fact - after playing around with the groovy console - it looks like `${ENV}` will try to call a function called `$` with the closure parameter `{ENV}` which in turn would return `'dev'`. It would give the same result as `ENV` if you would have defined a function like:

```
def $(Closure closure) {
    closure()
}
```

But most probably that's not what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 4):

Got this working in Jenkins:2.190.2 with a little groovy. Haven't tested on earlier versions. Just happens to be the one I'm on now. Works fine with multiple stages.

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    label "xxxxx"
  }
  environment {
    ROLE = getRole()
  }
  stages{
    stage("write to s3 etc") {
        environment {
            AWS = credentials("${ROLE}")
        }
        steps {
            script {
                sh"""
                    aws s3 sync build/ "s3://xxxxxxxxxxxx"
                """
            }
        }
      }
   }
}

def getRole() {
   def branchName = "${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
   if (branchName == "xxxxxx") {
      return 'some_credential_string'
   }
   else {
      return 'some_other_credential_string'
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I was looking on how to do this more nicely. This is a great solution.

Comment: Just for the guys with the same problem: "Internal function call parameters must be strings. " AWS = credentials(ROLE) does not work for unknown reasons.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use different credentials based on the condition, this could be done with the following example:

```
stage ("Example") {
  steps {
    script {
      if ( params.TEST_PARAMETER == "test_value1" ) {
        withCredentials([string(credentialsId: env.CREDENTIALS_1, variable: 'SOME_VARIABLE')]) {
          yourFunction()
        }
      }
      else {
        withCredentials([string(credentialsId: env.CREDENTIALS_2, variable: 'SOME_VARIABLE')]) {
          yourFunction()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You would need to define `yourFunction` in the end of your jenkinsfile. In this case, when `TEST_PARAMETER` is `test_value1` in the job, `CREDENTIALS_1` will be used from Jenkins credentials list. When `TEST_PARAMETER` is different, `CREDENTIALS_2` credentials will be used. You could have more options by modifying this to the case loop.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can simplify this with: string(credentialsId: getMyCredId(), ... ; because in the script context, it behaves as you would expect.